# checking the number of arguments before calling the method in Java

Tags: java

In my program, I have a method which is below;

```
private void foo(String title, String[] subtitles, int ... subtitleValues)
```

My requirement is ;

- number of subtitles and subtitleValues must be equal. User can send any number of subtitles and subtitle values but as I said **equal number of subtitles and subtitleValues.**

I don't want to take both arguments and check their counts in `foo` function and say your table can not be created because of unequal subtitles and subtitleValues. What I want is; prevent user to send unequal arguments. How can I do that?

Thanks in advance

PS : I didn't find a proper title, so if you have, please feel free to change it.

Comment: This is not a feature the compiler supports.  You can only do this at runtime, unless you write your own compiler. As your code will be properly tested ;), you can be reasonably sure this will not produce an error in production.

Comment: One way is to check it before the method is called, but I get the feeling that isn't what you're looking for :p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do it like this. What you *can* do to make your method harder to call wrongly is to use a fluent API for a builder like this:

```
class FooBuilder {
  public static FooBuilder withTitle(String title);
  public FooBuilder withSubtitle(String subtitle, int subtitleValue);
  public Foo build();
}
```

I left out the implementation for brevity. Then you can call it like this:

```
Foo foo = FooBuilder.withTitle("MyTitle").withSubtitle("st1", 1).withSubtitle("st2", 2).build();
```

Comment: this one is better than the other solutions for 2 reason: easy to read, no map/collection instanciation before call. I like it :)

Answer (score 2):

Create a class containing a subtitle, subtitleValue pair. Have your method accept a vararg (or list, or array) of instances of this class.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you should create probably separate class *Subtitle* which represents subtitles. And create appropriate constructor or method for adding subtitles one by one.

Then rephrase your foo method as:

```
private void foo(String title, List<Subtitle> subtitles)
```